# My div is NOT stacking left?

Tags: html, css

All I want is my two divs to stack next to one another. They are located inside a container. Why isn't it working?

This is my CSS:

```css
#housecontainer {
    height: 420px;
    width: 1000px;
    padding-left: 110px;
    padding-top: 80px;
}

#houseimage {
    float: left;
    height: 388px;
    width: 516px;
}

#rose {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: <div id="devcontainer">
   <div id="develbox">
     <div id="housecontainer">
  <div id="houseimage">
    <p><a href="images/rosebrook.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/rosebrookthumb.png" width="516" height="388"  />
      </a>
<div id="rose">THIS ISNT WORKING!!!</div></div>

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your HTML above? Also, since you're trying to put your divs _next_ to each other, you must nest the tags to do so. Another thing, when you have multiple divs with the same id, you are supposed to use _class_.

Comment: But this html is invalid. Structure is wrong and tags not closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the HTML you posted in your comment:

```
<div id="housecontainer">
    <div id="houseimage">
        <p>
            <a href="images/rosebrook.pdf" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/rosebrookthumb.png" width="516" height="388" />
            </a>
            <div id="rose">
                <div id="rose">THIS ISNT WORKING!!!</div>
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are a number of issues with this:

1. The `id` of an element must be unique. It is used to *identify* the element. In your markup there are two `div` elements with `id="rose"`.
2. From your question, it seems as if you want `#houseimage` and `#rose` to be side-by-side. This is not happening because `#rose` is *inside* `#houseimage`. That is, it is a child of `#houseimage`. You need to move it outside the `div` so that `#rose` is a sibling of `#houseimage`.

Change your HTML to be like this:

```
<div id="housecontainer">
    <div id="houseimage">
        <p>
            <a href="images/rosebrook.pdf" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/rosebrookthumb.png" width="516" height="388" />
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="rose">
        <div id="roseChild">THIS ISNT WORKING!!!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bGyV4/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You have several structure errors.

Try structuring your HTML like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bGyV4/

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the HTML you posted in your comment, your page structure is:

```
#devcontainer
  #develbox
    #housecontainer
      #houseimage
        p
          a
            img
        #rose
```

Since `#rose` is a child of `#houseimage`, it doesn't follow the same floating as it. Since `#houseimage` has a width of 516 and so does the image, there's no room left for `#rose` and it is forced below.

Just put one more `</div>` before `<div id="rose">`, so that it's inside `#housecontainer` and *next to* `#houseimage`, like you want. Then add the two other `</div>` you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

your html error,some `DIV` tag not closed,try this:

```
<div id="devcontainer">
    <div id="develbox">
        <div id="housecontainer">
            <div id="houseimage">
                <p>
                    <a href="images/rosebrook.pdf" target="_blank">
                        <img src="images/rosebrookthumb.png" width="516" height="388" />
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="rose">THIS ISNT WORKING!!!</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```